# why Java recursion code doesnt work properly? returns false output

Tags: java, recursion

Why does the recursion fail counting all possibilities but counts just one?

my code originally has meant to check the number of ways the numbers: 1,2,3,4 can be added in order to give a 10.
though it returns 1 every time...

I have been looking for an answer a lot online but got no good result, does someone know how to fix it?

the code:

```
public class main {
    static int count = 0;
    public static boolean work(int i){
        if (i == 10){
            count +=1;
            return true;
        }else if(i>10){
            return false;
        }
        return work(i+4)||work(i+3)||work(i+2)||work(i+1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        work(0);
        System.out.println(count);
        
    }

}
```

Comment: You call `work()` with a value of 10, which means that the first `if` condition is true. The method therefore sets count to 1 and returns. What else did you expect?

Comment: `i` will never be greater than 10. You start at 10 and then decrease it. What's that check even for? More generally, what is the program supposed to do?

Comment: Also, `count =+1;` you probably meant `count +=1;`?

Comment: Note that storing `count` in a static variable is dangerous, because you introduce possibilities like forgetting to reset it, thread interference etc. Instead, return the number of counts (e.g. 1 where you return true, zero where you return false, and add the things which are currently ||-d)

Comment: Now that you start with 0 the next problem shows up: due to the short circuit or (`||`) the recursion at `work(i+4)||work(i+3)||work(i+2)||work(i+1)` stops as soon as the first valid result (i.e. 4+4+2) is found.

Comment: What's the expected output for this code? Can you reuse numbers, like 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+3? Does order matter, so 3+3+3+1 is different than 1+3+3+3? Thanks for clarifying.